# Download official Google Play Services APK

Tags: android, google-play-services

Is there any official google service from where we can download Google Play Services APK?
I am using GCM on one of rugged devices for enterprise use, and for GCM will need Google Play Services APK.

I know APK is there at [apkmirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/) also at [androidapksfree](http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/google-play-services-apk-latest-version-download/) but since it is for enterprise use I cannot suggest APK from these sites or getting APK from rooted device.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any official google service from where we can download Google Play Services APK?

No. Play Services is licensed exclusively to device manufacturers as part of the Google Mobile Services package.

> I  am using GCM on one of rugged devices for enterprise use, and for GCM will need Google Play Services APK.

Either switch to a device that is a part of the Google Play ecosystem, or come up with a non-GCM solution for your communications.